# Getting random N rows by SQL query which will be proportional to the total number of rows in different sections

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that persists a lot of questions, each question belongs to a section:

```
Id      Question        SectionId
 1      What is ...     3
 2      Who is...       3
 3      When is...      2
 4      Why is...       1
 5      How is...       3
```

There is like 1000 questions, and around 50 sections. However, my query is simple, I select a given number of questions from the table from specific sections, for example

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Question] FROM [Questions] 
WHERE [SectionId] IN (1,2)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

This is simple and working fine, except that sometimes I get 5 questions out of the requested 10 from a section that has only 6 questions, and 2 from a section that has 100 questions, and 3 from a section that has 20 questions.

How can I make the result "proportional" with the number of the questions in each section. For example if I request 10 questions, I get more questions from the section that has more questions, and less questions from the sections with less questions.

The only I can think of currently is to make multiple queries, first one to get the number of questions in each section, then do some math and decide how many questions from each section, and then make another few queries to get the number of questions as I want. This sound intensive and I hope there's a more practical way.

Note: An SQL query, or EF Linq query would work.

Comment: *"How can I make the result 'proportional' with the number of the questions in each section."* At the risk of stating the obvious, that's not what *random N rows* means. That's an observation, not a criticism.

Answer (score 2):

For a stratified sample, do an nth sample on the ordering.  This is a little tricky, but this should work:

```
SELECT TOP (10) q.*
FROM (SELECT q.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY section, NEWID()) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY section, NEWID()) as cnt
      FROM [Questions] q
      WHERE [SectionId] IN (1, 2)
     ) q
ORDER BY seqnum % (cnt / 10);
```

There may be some boundary conditions on this logic, but as the number of questions grows and the sample is large enough, it should do what you want.

Comment: Keeps giving me `Divide by zero error encountered` even if the sections selected has questions.

Comment: @Him . . . I inverted the `order by` condition.  Of course, this requires that you have at least 10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do this in a single step, unless you know in advance the number of sections and the proportions of each.

If these values have to be calculated at query time, you will need to run a query to get the sections and proportions and use that to build a Dynamic SQL query.

Use a GROUP BY query to get the SectionIDs and the number of questions in each Section, filtered by the Sections you want to include.

Iterate through that result to build a dynamic UNION ALL query that gets a TOP n (calculate n based on the percentage of the Section's Count / Total Count) of questions for each Section (one query per section), so that you end up dynamically building something that looks something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 ID, Question --because SectionID 1 is 50% of the questions
FROM Questions
WHERE SectionID=1
ORDER BY NEWID()
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 3 ID, Question  --because SectionID 2 is 30% of the questions
FROM Questions
WHERE SectionID=2
ORDER BY NEWID()
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 2 ID, Question  --because SectionID 3 is 20% of the questions
FROM Questions
WHERE SectionID=3
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Another approach you could think about is to create an artificial ranking column that is factored by the relative density of the section.

What I mean, for example (super simplifying it) is suppose Section 1 was 75% of the questions, and Section 2 was 25%.

You'd use ROW_NUMBER(), partitioned by `SectionID`, ordered by NEWID() and factored so that:

Section 1 would have values like 1,2,3,5,6,7, etc (3 out of every 4 cardinal values)

Section 2 would have values like 1, 5, 9, 10 etc  (1 out of every 4)

Then Order your query result by this artificial column.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested in the absence of sample data, however, something like this might work:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Question,
           SectionID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN,
           (COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SectionID) / (COUNT(ID) OVER () *1.0)) *10 AS Perc 
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT TOP 10
       ID,
       Question,
       SectionID
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= CEILING(Perc)
ORDER BY RN ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, for example...return 20% of total rows per section

```
DECLARE @percentage numeric(10,2)

SET @percentage = 0.20 --20% of total question for section

SELECT [SectionID],[ID],[Question]
FROM (  SELECT
            [ID],
            [Question],
            [SectionID],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SectionID ORDER BY NEWID()) [idx],
            COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY SectionID) * @percentage AS [Proportional]
        FROM [Questions]) tbl
WHERE 
    (tbl.[SectionID] = 1 AND tbl.[idx] <= [Proportional])
OR (tbl.[SectionID] = 2 AND tbl.[idx] <= [Proportional])
OR (tbl.[SectionID] = 3 AND tbl.[idx] <= [Proportional])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NTILE(100) function along with a over clause partition by section to get

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Question] FROM [Questions] 
WHERE [SectionId] IN (1,2)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

should be

```
declare @limit int = 10;

;with data as (
   SELECT NTILE(100) over (partition by sectionid ORDER BY NEWID() ) as Centile, [Id], [Question] 
   FROM [Questions] 
   WHERE [SectionId] IN (1,2)
)
select * from data where centile <= @limit
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You could select always 10% of your records in any sections with this:

```
SELECT TOP ( select CAST(( COUNT(*) * 0.1 ) AS INT ) 
FROM QUESTION WHERE SECTIONID IN ( 1,2)) * FROM QUESTION 
WHERE [SectionId] IN (1,2)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```